# How to read and store file content into a variable either using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, filereader

I have one text file which is having some content and located in my local machine(like: `C:\Users\Test.txt`). I wanted to read this file and store it's content in one variable using either `javascript` or `jquery` or `html5 FileReader`? How can I do it ?

If I try the below, I am getting: `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource`.

js:

```
(function (sf) {
 "use strict";
 $.get( "C:/Users/Test.txt", function( data ) {
 var filecontent = data;// filecontent var should be having my file content data
});
}(samplefunction));
```

or

```
(function (sf) {
    "use strict";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'C:/Users/Test.txt',
        success: function (filedata) {
             alert('success : ' + filedata);
             var filecontent = filedata;
        }
    });
}(samplefunction));
```

Please let me know that how can I read and get my file content into my variable so that I can work on my remaining things. Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can't load off a file from the file system. Obvious security reasons. The user has to pick the file via f.ex. input filed of type file.

Comment: You need to include file in your website if you want to read it.

Comment: @K3N, Thank you for your reply, as I don't have any option to upload a file via <inpiut> type field, as I have a file(in some location) so that I need to get it's content. How can I get ? Yeah, I am getting those security issues  !

Comment: @Leopard, Thank you for your reply, yes I am including like: C:\Users\Text.txt, or like any ? I don't have option to upload via <input> field and can get the content from it !

Comment: @Guna: you can not strait way access local directories form the web as the above explained. but there are way to mount local directories to access by the web so that you can access the files from that directory. it has to be done by the server configuration level. this is not a solution but you may get a hit to move forward. it may be depend on the server used this may have help on tomcat http://harkiran-howtos.blogspot.com/2009/08/map-external-directory-into-your.html

Answer (score 0):

set up a local server such as IIS or Apache, and deploy your site into the server and access your file starts with "http://localhost/" or "http://127.0.0.1/"